# Error when finding the correlation between binary variables in R?

Tags: r, correlation

I have a list of variables (10) that are binary/factor variables. E.g. people who got a particular side effect vs people who did not. I want to find the correlation between these variables. Whether one variable is related/correlated to another. I can't use the cor function in  R since this only deals with continuous/quantitative data. So I am using the tetrachoric function.

```
correlation_data <- Toxicity %>% dplyr::select('variable1', 'variable2', 'variable3', 'variable4', etc....) %>% na.omit()

correlation_data [] <- lapply(correlation_data, factor)

install.packages("psych")
library(psych)
tetrachoric(correlation_data)
```

However, I get an error saying:

```
Error in t(x) - mx : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I am not sure what this means? How do I overcome this error?

Answer (score 0):

The data have to be numeric (and binary in this case).  You can see that if the data are numeric it works, but if they are factors it does not:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(psych)
bins <- matrix(rbinom(250, 1, .25), ncol=10)
bins <- as.data.frame(bins)
tetrachoric(bins)
#> Warning in cor.smooth(mat): Matrix was not positive definite, smoothing was done
#> Call: tetrachoric(x = bins)
#> tetrachoric correlation 
#>     V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9    V10  
#> V1   1.00                                                      
#> V2   0.47  1.00                                                
#> V3  -0.18  0.02  1.00                                          
#> V4  -0.17  0.03  0.65  1.00                                    
#> V5   0.11 -0.10 -0.26 -0.26  1.00                              
#> V6   0.38  0.45 -0.06 -0.36 -0.18  1.00                        
#> V7  -0.06 -0.28 -0.06 -0.08 -0.16  0.28  1.00                  
#> V8  -0.33 -0.19  0.02  0.03 -0.10  0.14  0.41  1.00            
#> V9  -0.25 -0.65 -0.26 -0.22  0.32 -0.47  0.51 -0.10  1.00      
#> V10 -0.26 -0.10  0.11  0.11  0.00  0.23  0.24  0.33 -0.01  1.00
#> 
#>  with tau of 
#>   V1   V2   V3   V4   V5   V6   V7   V8   V9  V10 
#> 0.99 0.71 0.99 0.99 0.84 0.58 0.58 0.71 0.25 0.84

bins <- bins %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), as.factor))

tetrachoric(bins)
#> Error in t(x) - mx: non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>